# How to cheat at cards

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, probability, cards

I have a deck of 52 cards on the table in front of me, in random order, each one randomly facing either up or down. I place one joker at each end, each of these again randomly facing either up or down, to get a deck of 54 cards.

I then perform a sequence of moves each of the following form.

> Choose a random contiguous block of cards (a certain number $\geq1$ of cards, all together in the deck) such that both the top and bottom card are facing up, and flip it over as a single unit.

What is the probability that eventually I can no longer perform such a move, i.e. all the cards are facing down?

Comment: I feel like something's missing.  What happens to the cards after they are flipped over?

Comment: And: is the goal to get all cards facing down or to prove that eventually no move exists?

Comment: The statement, *"What is the probability that eventually I can no longer perform such a move, i.e. all the cards are facing down?"* doesn't appear self-consistent.  It is possible to have one, and only one, card facing up, which would make it impossible to perform such a move, but wouldn't fulfill the *"...all cards are facing down,"* statement.  Please clarify which is correct, given that the answer you've accepted does not discuss this case.

Comment: @AdamDavis A single face-up card constitutes a "contiguous block of cards (a certain number ≥1 of cards, all together in the deck) such that both the top and bottom card are facing up", so a move would be possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The probability is

> 1.

If you

> represent all face-up cards as 1 and face-down cards as 0, the binary number representing the deck (concatenating the states from top to bottom) decreases every time. It can never drop below 0, of course, so you have to eventually stop flipping cards.

Comment: Exception: The number 1 cannot be reduced, because there is no second card facing up with which to define a *flppable* block. Likewise for any other pattern that represents a power of two.

Comment: Likewise for the pattern 5, or any pattern such as 10, 20, 40, etc., representing a left-shift of 5.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens 5 would work - flip 101 to get 010. And I never said you had to be able to keep flipping until you got to 0 - I just proved that it was impossible to flip infinitely.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens If you check the OP, I said the block of cards you choose to flip can be only 1 card thick. So when the process stops, all the cards _must_ be face-down. Also, good job Deusovi!

Comment: @apm: of course there are plenty of possibilities. You can turn any set of cards you want in that situation.

Comment: One card counts as a continguous block of >= 1 cards with both ends facing the same way, so you can flip one card at a time if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove the number of move is limited recursively on a group of n cards:
n = 1 means you have one move possible, afterward, you are stuck.

Let's suppose the hypothesis true for n >= 1 and let's take n + 1 cards.

> There is a limited number of move involving only the n first cards. after a moment, you would either be stuck or would turn the last card. After that, this card would be face down, no moves will be able to involve this last card and you are then limited to the n first cards.

There is therefore, only a finite number of moves possible.

> The solution is 1

Answer (score 0):

> The gap between the first and the last card facing up always narrows or stays the same, without ever going beyond the old gap. Eventually there'll be no usable cards *inside* a gap between facing-up cards even if we try to avoid moves narrowing it (the time for the widest gap will come), so there will be no cards left. In other words, the answer is 1.